# How do I make the Integer Data Type on the Parameter update the numbers automatically when workbook opens in Tableau?

Tags: dynamic, parameters, integer, tableau-api

I am having an issue automatically updating/refreshing the percentages on my donut chart. I created a parameter & plugged it into my calculated field but every time I close my dashboard & open it back up, I have to manually update the parameter so that the percentages update on the donut.  I have tried going to the "Value when workbook opens" field in the paramter but the only field from my data source that comes up is the "Donut" value that I used to create my actual donut chart. The value of the donut field is 0 of course since this was just used to create my donut.

I also went to the "List" view in the paramter & the "When workbook opens" has the same option(donut).
[image]

Why is this?

How do I get the percentages to be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I just did a quick table calculation & selected "Percent of Total" & it worked. This is an alternative to the parameter.